# Bigquery query result to dataframe with Airflow

Tags: sql, pandas, dataframe, google-bigquery, airflow

I am trying to query the data from bigquery and write it to dataframe with Airflow. But either it is giving `file not found` (service account key) or `file name is too long` or `eof line read` error.

I have tried with hooks as well but I am not able to do put key file as json as it is saying it is too long.

Any tips on how I can achieve it?

```
def get_data_from_GBQ():

global customer_data
ofo_cred = Variable.get("ofo_cred")
logging.info(ofo_cred)
logging.info("Variable is here")
customer_data_query = """ SELECT FirstName, LastName, Organisation FROM `bigquery-bi.ofo.Customers` LIMIT 2 """
logging.info("test")

# Creating a connection to the google bigquery
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(ofo_cred)
logging.info("after client")
customer_data = client.query(customer_data_query).to_dataframe()
logging.info("after client")
print(customer_data)

dag = DAG(
'odoo_gbq_connection',
default_args=default_args,
description='A connection between ',
schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),)
```

And the error is:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '{\r\n  "type": "service_account",\r\n  "project_id":...
```

Comment: I'm curious about why you saw 3 different kind of error message. Could you add more detail to your question?

Comment: Would be great to see your DAG's code. Please prepare minimal example

Comment: @YunZhang I am not seeing 3 of them together. Every time, when I am trying new things it is throwing different error :(

Comment: @ArtemVovsia I have updated. Could you please check it? It is a logging variable totally normal, but during authorization, it is throwing the error above. I have no clue why.

Comment: Are you using open source Airflow or Cloud Composer?

Comment: @ArtemVovsia path is also not happening as it is saying file not found, which is so weird

Comment: @jjayadeep I am using open source one.

Comment: Thanks people solved it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json` function expects file name of the service account file, you provide it with the contents of that file, so it tries to find the file which path starts with `{\r\n  "type": "servi...` and it fails with `FileNotFound`.

Potential fix:

```py
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(path_to_ofo_cred)
```

https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html#service-accounts